# Integrating $\int \sqrt{a^2+x^2} \ \mathrm{d} x$ with trig. substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to come up with all the formulas I have myself and I stumbled upon a roadblock again.
Integrating $\int \sqrt{a^2+x^2} \ \mathrm{d} x$ with Trig Substitution.

So I imagined a triangle where the hypotenuse is $1$, $\sin(y) = x$ opposite over hypotenuse and $\cos(y) = a$ adjacent over hypotenuse.

Then $dx = \cos(y)dy$ and factoring out the a out of the square root,
I get $ \int a $ $\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{a^2}} \ \mathrm{d} x$ or $ \int  \sqrt{1+\tan y^2}\cos y^2 \ \mathrm{d} y$
which I could simplify to $\int \cos y \ \mathrm{d} y$. This gives me the wrong answer.

Can you pinpoint or hint at where I am going wrong with my substitution once more?
Apologies, I appreciate it.

Comment: Substitute $x= a\tan y$ .

Comment: No 'dx' or 'dy' at the end? Sacreligious! I've edited the post to add them in for you.

Comment: @TobyMak Thank you haha I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the integral $$\int\sqrt{a^2+x^2} dx $$ $a$ is supposed to be a constant, and you can’t just make it dependent on the variable of integration, by saying $a=\cos y$. The straightforward approach would be to substitute $x=a\tan y \implies dx=a\sec^2y dy$ To get$$\int a^2\sec^3y\  dy$$

Comment: Hi Tavish, thank you, I think I get it. Actually yours was the first substitution I tried, and then I made the mistake of setting secy to $\frac{1}{a}$ Thanks a lot!

Comment: @oliver You’re very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I will not the give he same answer as others   but if you cannot do these integrals despite many tries, this is a sure shot way to get correct answers.

Substitute $x  = ai\sin(y)⟹y= \arcsin(\frac{x}{ai})$

$dx = ai\cos(y)dy$
$$I = \int \sqrt{a^2 +(i a \sin y)^2} \cdot ai\cos(y) dy$$

$$I = \int \sqrt{a^2 - a^2\sin^2y} \cdot ai\cos(y) dy$$
$$I = a^2i\int \cos(y) \cdot  \cos(y) dy$$
$$I = \frac{a^2i}{2} \Biggr(y + \cos y \sin y \Biggr)$$
$$I = \frac{a^2i}{2} \Biggr( \arcsin\biggr(\frac{x}{ai}\biggr) +  \sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{a^2}}\cdot\biggr(\frac{x}{ai}\biggr)\Biggr)$$
Use $\arcsin(x) = -i\ln|\sqrt{1-x^2} + ix|$ to get the final answer,

Comment: Thank you for the alternative, I do not completely get how you came up with this, but it's quite intriguing and I will explore this as well. Cheers

Comment: I thought to give this a try and it worked out fortunately. I don't know whether you will find this in any textbooks, I haven't seen any.:)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=a\tan\theta\implies dx=a\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$
$$\int \sqrt{a^2+x^2}dx=\int \sqrt{a^2+a^2\tan^2\theta}\ a\sec^2\theta \ d\theta$$
$$=\int a\sec\theta\ a \sec^2\theta \ d\theta$$
$$=a^2\int \sec^3\theta \ d\theta$$

Using integration by parts
$$=a^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\sec\theta \tan\theta+\frac12\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|\right)+C$$
substituting back to $x$,
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(x\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+a^2\ln|x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2}|\right)+C$$

Comment: @downvoter(s) But I have not understood the downvote. What is the reason?

Comment: Yes, I too don't know. Perhaps they don't want to explain but quick to downvote.

Comment: Thank you Harish, I will try this one too

Comment: [The use of IBP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed#Higher_odd_powers_of_secant) generalizes to integrating other powers of the secant function.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you for giving this generalized or reduction formula. I know this is result by IBP.

Comment: This actually isn't terrible answer, little bit beneath you and shnobbish but I down vote.